# Creating log of when computer loses internet connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

My computer is far away from the wireless router that provides internet. I have been experiencing connection issues, such as random short (or long) dropped connections. I have notified the owner of the router but she says she needs some statistic information, such as date and time etc. What options are available? I consider running `ping` continuous, but a lost packet may not be the fault of the internet connection. I use a desktop VPN (using TCP) which may affect the situation.

TL;DR how can I measure and take record of when my computer looses connection to the internet?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824477/script-to-start-traceroute-if-ping-fails-output-to-log-help-please/#6837400

Comment: @wysiwyg that just pings google.com which I don't think is a good idea as, in theory, the google server could be down or a hope along the way could be down. Could it ping a few different servers and only record if none reply?

Comment: Google servers can be down. Hmmm, Possible? Yes. Probable? Not really.

Comment: @EddyEd pinging is the generally accepted way to test internet connectivity. It's probably possible to write a script as you suggest but that's beyond the scope of my knowledge...

Comment: Your wireless router does NOT provide internet access. It provides NETWORK access. These two things are COMPLETELY unrelated. You need to make it clear whether this question is about LAN connectivity or Internet connectivity. See Bullet #2 from this poster: https://wirelessaction.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/4-myths-about-wi-fi.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it but [Net Uptime Monitor](https://netuptimemonitor.com/) seems to do what you want by pinging 3 different servers:

> The Net Uptime Monitor alerts you to failures in your internet
>   connection and documents the exact time and length of those failures.
>
> Net Uptime Monitor (NUM) uses the “Ping” command to test the response
>   from three public servers operated by Google, Level 3, and OpenDNS. Each server is pinged
>   in turn at an interval that you can set – normally five seconds. By
>   default, NUM waits 200 milliseconds (2/10 of a second) for the server
>   to respond – at least 3 times as long as a typical internet connection
>   should take.

They have a free trial and a single-user license is $9.95